# Analysis of a realtime geodata stream

Tags: php, python, c++, hadoop, apache-storm

I have the following position stream, which i can access via a web interface:

```
http://positionstub/interface/
```

It delivers the information (latitude/longitude), where a vehicle is at the moment. It refreshes with a rate of 10hz.

```
<response>   
    <data>
        <position object="vehicle1" lat="22.268764" long="0.351563" />
        <position object="vehicle2" lat="22.288704" long="3.142" />
    </data>
</response>
```

I now have geofences, that are defined in an XML-file, for example an rectangle, that has the following measurements:

```
<geofences>
    <area id="area1" lat_min="22.103232" lat_max="22.103280" long_min="3.142323" long_max="3.142368"></area>
<geofences>
```

1.)Is there a suitable way / application to analyze this data stream, to detect online whether an vehicle is inside or outside of this geofence?

Finally, this information (in/out of an vehicle in a geofence) should be saved in a database, so that it can be processed by other applications.

I have read about the Storm realtime computation system: http://storm-project.net/

Is it possible to implement such an geofencing functionality with this tool? Or should i write a piece of c++ software to do this job?

So far i have only experience with web technologies like PHP and JS. How can i solve this problem? How can i efficiently analyze this data stream online?

Furthermore, it would be nice if i can analyze this stream for complex events.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can build something like this in Storm, and it's a good choice since you are dealing with things that Storm is really good at (a continuous stream of data, easily parallelizable computations.

Also, since you mention PHP and JS, you can write the components of your Storm topology in anything you like even if it's not a JVM language, although the Clojure DSL for Storm is very nice and easy to use.

As an aside, if you are comfortable with JavaScript and don't want to deal with learning Storm, you might want to consider building this using Node.js.

Answer (score 3):

Esri's new GeoEvent Processor for ArcGIS has exactly what you need.  It's not going to be cheap though.

I'm not sure what the SO policy is on advertising/promoting non-free software, so forgive me if this seems spammy.  I don't work for Esri.  I won't provide a link but you can easily Google it.